# Access violation only in release x64

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I am getting access violation in very weird circumstances with the `<random>` header. Is this a compiler bug? Here is the code:

```
#include <random>

class Foo {
public:
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937_64 mt;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist;

    Foo();
};

Foo::Foo() : mt(rd()) {
    dist = std::uniform_int_distribution<int>(0, 1);
}

int main() {
    Foo foo;

    int a[2];

    int b[2] = { 0 };

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        int c = foo.dist(foo.mt);
        a[0] = b[c];
        b[c] = b[0];
    }
}
```

If I instead replace the for-loop with the following, the code works without access violation!

```
{
    int c = foo.dist(foo.mt);
    a[0] = b[c];
    b[c] = b[0];
}

{
    int c = foo.dist(foo.mt);
    a[0] = b[c];
    b[c] = b[0];
}
```

This only applies to Release x64 and I started out with an "Empty project". To me this seems like a bug. Am I missing something?

Comment: Output the value of the variable 'c'.

Comment: The answer to the question "is this a compiler bug" is "almost certainly no".

Comment: Aren't you curious as to what the value of `c` may be?

Comment: printing the value of `c` stops it crashing...

Comment: Clearly a compiler bug... report it: Help -> Send Feedback -> Report a Problem...

Comment: you can see the code generated at https://godbolt.org/z/CfRaTI

Comment: I reproduced the crash in x64 release mode in Visual Studio 2019. Version 16.1.3

Comment: Reproduced in Visual Studio 2017, Ver 15.9.11. Example from cppref in similar conditions works well https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution

Comment: It does not crash if you output `c`.

Comment: Yes, I tried that too. This is also part of my phrasing "very weird cirumstances". It seems that rustyx is right and I will report it. @drescherjm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug with the optimizer where it applies a pattern meant for signed integers to unsigned integers.

I reported the bug and David Hartglass at Microsoft responded [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/672003/suspected-compiler-bug-only-in-release-x64.html). The bug is currently being worked on.